# Post to LinkedIn using Share API

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkedin-api

I'm facing difficulty in implementing LinkedIN Share Api in  Asp.net application . Can any one help me ?
  I found the documentation for the `LinkedIN Share API`  (https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-api). 
  It is saying that i should create a XML for sharing and should post this to the URL "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares"

I have two doubts after reading this document

1. How to pass the tokens to the server along with the XML, it is not told in the documentation?
2. What should be he name/key of the  XML Content Posted?

Requirement is : I need to share an update ("just a text ) to a users linked in  account.
The text to share is given by the user through a text box(so it will only contain text)

I'm Using `LinkedIn OAuth Library 0.6.1 For Authentication`. Since i didn't find any method (that helps to post) in this library, i'm planning to use Share API directly. And Post to Linkedin by Using the class "`HttpWebRequest`"

What i did till now:

1.Created a app in linked in, so i got App-Key and App-Key
2.In order to Authenticate, redirects the user to linked in  using the BeginAuthMethod in the OAuth Library 0.6.1 like this

```
var token = OAuthManager.Current.CreateToken(callback: this.AppRedirectUrl);
OAuthManager.Current.BeginAuth (token, endResponse: true, displayAllowDenyScreen: false);
```

3.After Authentication i receive the response from linked in and i use that auth-token to fetch the usertoken like this

```
var token = OAuthManager.Current.GetTokenInCallback();
var session = OAuthManager.Current.CompleteAuth(token);
this.UserToken = token.Token;
this.UserSecret = token.TokenSecret;
```

4.I have created a XML somewhat like this :

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<share>
    <comment>83% of employers will use social media to hire: 78% LinkedIn, 55% Facebook, 45% Twitter [SF Biz Times] http://example.com</comment>
    <content>
         <title>Survey: Social networks top hiring tool - San Francisco Business Times</title>
    </content>
    <visibility>
        <code>anyone</code>
    </visibility>
</share>
```

5.So now i have the App-Key, App-Secret, User-Token and User-Secret , and i have the xml and the url to post (ie http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares)

How to post this xml to the url using the tokens?. Can any one give some/any information regarding this?

I came across an example in java doing the same. the link is "https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/writing-linkedin-apis".But i need this in .NET

Comment: i made a post using LinkedIn Rest-Console,see request generated
`POST /v1/people/~/shares HTTP/1.1
Authorization:
OAuth oauth_consumer_key="w_1233373R-J97_wH3_131231kL9netWMe90_OM1233gQzip-ssCmwKWyJU",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="11233865",oauth_nonce="20012339",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_token="5f3c5cf2-e661-41bd-1230-274312361",oauth_signature="Fdw6%2BJh2133123brPeZGY%3D"
Host:
api.linkedin.com
Content-Length:
634
X-Forwarded-For:
10.203.10.109
X-Target-URI:
http://api.linkedin.com
Content-Type:
application/xml
Connection:
Keep-Alive

[Here Comes XML]`

Comment: In the Above request there are many keys
`in which some of them i have with me they are 
OAuth oauth_consumer_key = [App Key], oauth_token = [Auth_tokn] `
But `i dont have some other keys like : oauth_signature,  oauth_nonce‌`
**How can i generate these keys?**

Answer (score 7):

Use this method to post to LinkedIn shares. The method assumes that you have the `accesstoken` handy.

```
private string linkedinSharesEndPoint = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?oauth2_access_token={0}";
private const string defaultUrl = "some-url";
private const string defaultImageUrl = "some-image-url";

public bool PostLinkedInNetworkUpdate(string accessToken, string title, string submittedUrl = defaultUrl, string submittedImageUrl = defaultImageUrl)
{
    var requestUrl = String.Format(linkedinSharesEndPoint, accessToken);
    var message = new
    {
        comment = "Testing out the LinkedIn Share API with JSON",
        content = new Dictionary<string, string>
        { { "title", title },
            { "submitted-url", submittedUrl },
            {"submitted-image-url" , submittedImageUrl}
        },
        visibility = new
        {
            code = "anyone"
        }
    };

    var requestJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(message);

    var client = new WebClient();
    var requestHeaders = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "Content-Type", "application/json" },
        { "x-li-format", "json" }
    };
    client.Headers.Add(requestHeaders);
    var responseJson = client.UploadString(requestUrl, "POST", requestJson);
    var response = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(responseJson);
    return response.ContainsKey("updateKey");
}
```

Please note that I have made the `submittedUrl` and the `submittedImageUrl` optional.

Comment: It was your comment about optional submitted url that got me to discover the answer to my problem. Thanks! +1

Comment: How to get the user linkedin post ??

Comment: It is not possible, you must create them outside of linkedin if you want to have  a copy of them. Best strategy is to create them on your backend and use this API to share.

Comment: How to get access token?